# Interface Boundary Conditions for Transverse Wave in 3D

Tags: waves

Assuming that reflection and transmission occur at the interface and $\psi$ is the wave displacement satisfying the wave equation, does the following apply?
$$\vec\nabla({\Psi_{i}+\Psi_{r}})=\vec\nabla{\Psi_{t}}$$
The indices $i,r,t$ corresponds to incident, reflected, and transmitted wave, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the wave is a transverse-displacament  wave, with wavevector perpendicular to the interface between two different elastic media at $x=0$ you only have
$$
\Psi_I+\Psi_r=\Psi_t
$$
at $(x=0,y,z)$. In general you know  know nothing about derivatives in the $x$ direction. If you have more information about elastic properties, then you can use energy conservation to get information about the $x$ derivative, but there will be no reason, in general, for the $x$ derivative to be continuous across the interface.